# how to remove from FB app user_friends permission?

Tags: facebook

By default, user_friends is granted and approved for any new FB app.
I believe this let new users not interested as of privacy risk.
how to disable user_friends permission from my app?
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Use API v2.0. In API v2.0 there is no default permissions so you need to ask exactly for the permissions you want.

In API v1.0 it is not possible to not ask for user_friends.